# Inno Setup How can I make uninstall automatically after specific date

Tags: inno-setup

I have some folders and files that are installed to directory `C:\`. 
I want to uninstall or delete that folders and files after one year automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Just schedule the uninstall to be run at the specified date.

Use [`schtasks.exe` tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks). See also [How to add a scheduled task with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12250151/850848).

An simple example:

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/Create /RL HIGHEST /SC ONCE /SD ""{code:GetUninstallDate}"" /ST 00:00 /F /TN ""Uninstall My App"" /TR ""'{uninstallexe}' /verysilent"""; \
    Flags: runhidden

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/Delete /F /TN ""Uninstall My App"""; \
    Flags: runhidden
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetUninstallDate(Param: string): string;
var
  Year, NextYear: string;
begin
  { schtasks needs localized date string }
  Result := GetDateTimeString('ddddd', #0, #0);
  { calculate the next year }
  Year := GetDateTimeString('yyyy', #0, #0);
  NextYear := IntToStr(StrToInt(Year) + 1);
  StringChange(Result, Year, NextYear);
end;
```

Comment: Martin how i test that

Comment: 1st test: Just run the created task manually from Windows Scheduler. If that works, 2nd test: Re-install and move the clock to the future, just a minute before the schedule time and wait. The same as with [inno setup create application valid for one year](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36823585/850848).

Comment: sorry martin can you explain how ?

Comment: 1st test what is Windows Scheduler.

Comment: In *Control Panel*, go to *System and Security > Administrative Tools > Schedule Tasks*.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler and http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task

Comment: I can't find any Task has a relation with uninstall

Comment: Yes after installed no task created.and sure I run the Schedule Tasks as administrator.its no log file created.I can print screen for Tasks Schedule and share it for you.

Comment: You have to run the installer with `/log=C:\path\to\setup.log` switch.

Comment: I can't find it but this what i'm doing                                                                     ![valid XHTML][checkmark].                                                                                                         [checkmark]: http://postimg.org/image/ubgmzlwep/                                             Sorry i can't upload image in right way

Comment: What you cannot find? You have add the `/LOG` to the `setup.exe` command line = meaning you have to run it manually yourself, not from the studio. Or you do not know where you `setup.exe` is or what? The option you set is compiler log, not installation log. In studio, you enable the installer log on "Compiler settings" page, the "Setup logging" option. You cannot specify a file name there. It logs to the `%TEMP%`.